# EJB is not abstract and does not override abstract method fix solution?

Tags: java, netbeans

I get this error in the EJB class I tried to see in the other questions but I couldn't solve it, can anyone help me? Thanks

"CanzoneEJB is not abstract and does not override abstract method cercaPerSerataEsibizione(Integer) in CanzoneEJBRemote"

[CanzoneEJB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RxX0.png)

[Method CanzoneEJB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2iCg.png)

[CanzoneEJBRemote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LBVh.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to replace images of code with your code. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `cercaPerSerataEsibizione` in the CanzoneEJBRemote interface takes an **Integer**, but the corresponding method in CanzoneEJB class takes a **String**. Since the abstract method and the overriding method have different types for the `serataesibizione` parameter, the method is not overridden and Java gives an error.

Either change the aforementioned method in CanzoneEJBRemote to take a String, or change the method in CanzoneEJB to take an Integer.